# How to hijack scroll page only in some part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a longform and I'm getting crazy with the desktop version.
For the mobile everything is ok, but for desktop I want to hijack the scroll only on several part of the page.

Basically I want to insert a gallery like this

[Pen Gallery](https://codepen.io/slstudios/pen/XbgVBY)

Between paragraph of text. You scroll, you read the text, when you arrive at the gallery the page stops scrolling and the gallery scrolls until the end of the images, then the page start to scroll again to the next gallery.

I'm thinking to set some waypoint to change the `data-hijacking="off"` attribute of the body, but maybe there is a batter way. This pen is derived from a 4 years old demo.